# Response from a discord bot in discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot for my server in discord and I want it to interact with users when they say something along the lines of, "Im, ". For example, if someone says "I'm tired." my bot would say, "Hey tired, Im HalogenBot" (Thats the name of my bot).

So my best guess was to use

```
if message.content.startswith('im'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, '')
```

I have no idea what to write in the response. 
I would need to have the bot copy the message and somehow get rid of the "im" from the message, and then the rest is simple I just make it state that it is halogen bot.

Also I know my code is ugly, I am in the beginning stage of my work on this bot and have not touched up yet

Any help? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the message in `message.content` (for instance "I'm tired"). You can use `string.replace` to remove the part that is not interesting for you.

```
adjective = message.content.replace("I'm ", "")
response = "Hello {}, I'm HalogenBot".format(adjective)
```

If you feel you might have long content but only want the first word after "I'm", don't forget to crop the rest using `split`:

```
adjective = message.content.replace("I'm", "").split(" ")[0]
```

Comment: So one more problem, the bot detects the "im" in the message it sends and then starts an infinite loop of responses because everytime he says "Hi im halogen bot" it sees the im and DOES NOT STOP.

Comment: From what you say, I guess you are somehow streaming all messages from an API, is that right? If so, have you checked if you can access the user sending the message (maybe `message.user`)? You could then filter out messages from your bot by adding a condition (`if message.user != "halogen"`) before it enters the part where you send a message.

Comment: i used "if client.user.id !=". Thank you so much man you've been a big help